# Is there a nice way to simulate a "Maybe" or "option" type in Go?

Tags: types, go, nullable

I'm sending a reply to a request over a `chan X`, where `X` is a struct. The request is a search operation, so ideally I'd like to be able to return either an `X`, or report it wasn't found.

This would be a task for a `Maybe X` in Haskell or an `x option` in OCaml. Is there any decent way to do this in Go? I'm not returning a pointer (as the original object I'm returning might be modified later), so I can't just return `nil`.

**Edit:** right now I'm making it a `chan interface{}` and either sending an `X` or `nil`, but this is ugly and defeats type-safety.

Comment: in https://github.com/alphazero/future.go I opted for the tuple (interface{}, flag) as the channel payload.  Interestingly enough, pushed it yesterday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `interface {}` you're effectively returning a pointer now. Why not change `interface {}` to `*X` and make sure to return a copy of the object? If I understand your reasoning behind not using a `chan *X`, that is.

Comment: Uhh, yes you do. I suppose that is an option. Is the cheapest/easiest way to do that to call it `&*object`? (if that's even allowed (I shall check.))

Comment: The two ways I can think of without using the `reflect` package are `a := b; return &a` and `return &thistype{thisfield:b.thisfield, thisotherfield:b.thisotherfield}`. I haven't benchmarked, but the former uses fewer instructions.

Comment: It certainly uses less code, and is less of a maintenance issue, so I'll go with that. Cheers!

Answer (score 16):

I use the pointer type, where:

- `Maybe X` = `*X`
- `Nothing` = `nil`
- `Just x` = `&x`

Answer (score 5):

Another way would be to add an ok bool.  You could either add it to X or wrap X, like `struct {X; ok bool}`